# Any way or macro available for converting RGB TO CMYK mode

Tags: corel-draw

Any way or macro available for converting RGB TO CMYK mode for fill and outline at single click. I have to follow this steps Edit -> find and replace -> replace object -> replace a color model or palette -> find a color model -> (change which color model) Then click on replace color to fill -> finish
Same process i have to follow for the outlines if i have. Any quick way or macro. Suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: Why you would like to do that in workfile? It's easier IMHO to export or convert final pdf to CMYK as you convert en masse with selected profile.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY to print on rgb printer. And if needed CMYK TO RGB

Comment: Then it make no sense to change to CMYK. RGB printer will translate your CMYK to RGB and then to it's own CMYK.

Comment: Doing the conversion in the workfile is preferred to doing it after the file has been output - it makes it easier for the designer (and if it's going to a commercial printer, the prepress team) to have fine control over any color adjustments.

Comment: And a nitpicky pet-peve detail because I'm a pedant: Almost all printers, both commercial and desktop, use CMYK color models. Any printers marketed as RGB printers are just using additional inks and/or more robust ICC profiles to make it seem like they handle RGB better. Whether or not an RGB file prints better than a CMYK file on this equipment is highly dependent on the device and any profiles/conversion models being employed. Do some output tests before you  resign yourself to the idea that sending an RGB file to these printers will result in higher quality output.

Comment: @superluminal I FOUND IT . tHANKS